# ASP.net Core retorna localhost en RemoteIP del client, ¿por qué?

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-core

Aloha~ Buenas tardes, tengo una situación curiosa, en un Apache tengo un sistema hecho en ASP.net Core y cuando trato de usar `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();` la IP que me devuelve es `127.0.0.1` habiendo estado publicado en el servidor, donde, en teoría se reciben peticiones con su remote IP del cliente, ¿alguna idea de qué está faltando? En teoría debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elemental mi querido Watson, está faltando algo importante en el `Configure`. Recuerda que las cosas deben hacerse decentemente y con orden, veamos el código de tu `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
       {

        // ...
        //Esto es para que la IP remota sea la real de donde se envía el request.
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        //...
        }
```

Necesitarás incluir:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
```

Con esto podrás ver la IP de donde se realizan las peticiones y santo remedio :D